# I can't disable the user with the Keyrock API

Tags: api, fiware, idm

I want to disable or enable the user found in keyrock with API, but I can't. https://keyrock.docs.apiary.io/ doesn't say how to do it here. Isn't that possible?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WfHr.png)

Comment: Kindly go through this  link- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how should we post a question to get response.

Comment: question needs some more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Log in as an admin user via the REST API.

```sh
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:3005/v1/auth/tokens' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "admin@test.com",
  "password": "1234"
}'
```

The response header returns an `X-Subject-token` **Header** which identifies who has logged on the application. This token is required in all subsequent requests to gain access.

The image you give in the question is just a GUI version of the GET /users endpoint

```sh
curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:3005/v1/users' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'X-Auth-token: aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

Or you can request a specific user:

```sh
curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:3005/v1/users/bbbbbbbb-good-0000-0000-000000000000' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'X-Auth-token: aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

Returns:

```json
{
    "user": {
        "scope": [],
        "id": "bbbbbbbb-good-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "username": "bob",
        "email": "bob-the-manager@test.com",
        "enabled": true,
        "admin": false,
        "image": "default",
        "gravatar": false,
        "date_password": "2018-07-30T11:41:14.000Z",
        "description": "Bob is the regional manager",
        "website": null
    }
}
```

You want to set `enabled: false` using the PATCH /user endpoint.

```sh
curl -L -X PATCH 'http://localhost:3005/v1/users/bbbbbbbb-good-0000-0000-000000000000' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'X-Auth-token: aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' \
--data-raw '{
    "user": {
        "username": "bob",
        "email": "bob-the-manager@test.com",
        "enabled": false,
        "gravatar": false,
        "date_password": "2018-07-26T15:25:14.000Z"
    }
}'
```

More information can be found within the Security Chapter [Tutorials](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/identity-management.html)
within the FIWARE documentation where Keyrock is a component found within the [FIWARE Catalogue](https://github.com/FIWARE/catalogue)

In the FIWARE documentation an example is given using Keyrock to provide user identities around a [*"powered by FIWARE"* solution](https://fiware-marketplace.readthedocs.io/en/latest/solution/apply.html). Note that whilst Keyrock is commonly used  in  *"powered by FIWARE"* solutions (along with other elements from the FIWARE Catalogue), it could also be used to provide identities for other independent applications or micro-services - it is not tightly bound to only be used in FIWARE scenarios. Similarly alternative open-source or proprietary components for security or identity management systems could be used to secure  *"powered by FIWARE"* solution as well.